# Date FNS addWeeks and subWeeks

Tags: reactjs, date-fns

I am working on a React app using date fns. I have downloaded/imported it into my project and am able to use format, addMonths and other functions, but subWeeks and addWeeks are not working.

Anyone else experienced a similar issue?

Comment: What does the question has to do with the java tag? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).